# Is the tc driver in the Linux Kernel for Thin Clients or Telecine devices?

Tags: kernel, drivers, linux-kernel

Is the tc driver in the Linux Kernel source code (./drivers/tc) for Thin Clients or Telecine devices? I am wanting to learn the Linux kernel thoroughly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's for the [TURBOchannel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TURBOchannel) bus.